# CSS Body is higher when margin added

Tags: css, height, margin

I have a DIV #page, if I add a margin on top suddenly a scrollbar appears, even though the element is not bigger than the body. How can I get the scrollbar away?

(see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mZKC5/2/))

My HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="page">
    I am a div sized with calc()!
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
html, body {
height:100%;
}
body {
margin:0;
padding:0 10px 0 10px;
font-family:helvetica;
background:black;
color:yellow;
}
#page {
position:relative;
min-height:90%;
min-height:calc(100% - 60px);
width:100px;
padding:10px;
margin:20px auto;
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
```

Comment: It seems that element is actually 'bigger than body'... However - overflow-y: hidden on body will remove scrollbar, if you want it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**solution demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mZKC5/22/)

**Problem :**

Your div is `position`ed....so you have to apply `position`ing instead of `margin` in proper format...use `left`,`right` instead of `margin-left`etc

```
padding:10px;
margin:20px auto;
```

**Correct css**

```
#page {
    position:relative;
    min-height:90%;
    min-height:calc(100% - 60px);
    width:100px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 auto; /*center the div*/
    top:20px; /*proper assigned margin to kill v-scrollbar*/
    bottom:20px;/*proper assigned margin to kill v-scrollbar*/
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
```

**EDIT**

`Horizontal scroll would be there` because you have set `body` padding at `padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;`

If above padding is removed  **[there will be no horizontal scroll too](http://jsfiddle.net/mZKC5/24/)**`

Comment: Op's calc seems to be correct, and he wants a top margin on div.

Comment: Thats the reason I have calc(100%-60px) meaning it is 100% in total

Comment: @downvoter: please point out the problem and give some time to the poster to improve the answer before downvoting at lightening speed.

Comment: @abhitalks : yeah he is compensating the difference from the `calc`...but...ok let me add an explaination edit :)

Comment: @JSHelp : 1st edit added....working on giving you an explanation....not an answer ( *as this is what you asked* )...wud give proper answer in few mins...myself too digging in whats actually causing the prob!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor: +1 bcoz the downvoter didn't respond despite your efforts.

Comment: @NoobEditor: Good work. But, now we have a horizontal scrollbar. And there is no margin on the div which, the op wanted. But yes, good solution indeed!

Comment: @abhitalks he is using top and bottom instead, ya good work +1 already done anyway

Comment: @abhitalks that is bound to happen as `body` has `padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;` :)

Comment: @NoobEditor or remove `width:100%;` for BODY to get rid of horizontal scroll and still keeping padding

Comment: @A.Wolff : IMHO, I think keeping padding is a bad idea....rather, assign it to container `div`...because body needs to be `100%`...your thoughts??:)

Comment: @NoobEditor: padding on body will ensure that space for all elements, otherwise Op will have to apply that amount of extra margin on all elements.

Comment: @NoobEditor padding from body will be apply to elements inside so i guess it is better to keep it but i'm far from a CSS specialist.

Comment: @abhitalks : padded area is still unusable as content can't be placed in it unless you place a negative margin to place content there....is it not?? ...why not place it on container then?? :|

Comment: @NoobEditor: in this case the body *is* the container

Comment: Lets go guys. The Op is not interested.

Comment: @NoobEditor I don't really understand how come it makes such a great difference using `margin` or positioning with `top` `bottom`

Comment: @JSHelp : **simple thumb rule** =>`margin` is to be used when you do not use `position`....if you use `position` attribute, use `top`,`bottom` etc :)

Answer (score 3):

*Problem*: The `body` is by default `position:static`. Adding margin to a direct child will cause it to shift proportionately irrespective of its height.

*Solution*: Provide `position:fixed` to `body`, to prevent shifting and remove scrollbars.

*Demo*: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mZKC5/18/**

*CSS*:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
body {
    position: fixed; /* important to keep it fixed */
    margin: 0; padding: 0px 10px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    background: black; color: yellow;
}
#page {
    height: calc(100% - 60px); /* 10+10 padding + 20+20 margin = 60px is ok */
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
```

***Edit***: (per @AWolff's suggestion)

What the above demo shows is the reason body scrolls when margin is applied to the direct child. But, as a side-effect of making the `body` `fixed` is that it will no longer be scrollable at all even if you would want to add more relative content.

Better solution would be to use absolute positioning to place elements if you need pixel-perfection.

Or, follow @NoobEditors suggestion to use relative `positioning` instead of `margins`, relative because it will be relative to `body` anyways (even if it is absolute).

.

Comment: Wait, but then body is no more scrollable?!

Comment: @A.Wolff: Yes. That's what the Op asked: "*How can I get the scrollbar away?*"

Comment: @abhitalks so why not just use overflow: hidden; or set the DIV as absolute ?

Comment: @A.Wolff: Agree with you completely. The Op wanted to know why body scrolls, so wanted to let him see that. But, yes I will add that to the answer.

Comment: Checking it i see in dev tool than BODY seems to take 20px of margin from top (html?). I cannot explain it :(

Comment: @abhitalks : i figured it out...check my answer :)

Comment: @abhitalks : its the syntaxt in assigning the `margin-top/bottom`, which is causing the trouble....took me by surprise too!! :)

Comment: @A.Wolff: Just checked. The body isn't taking 20px, the div is.

Comment: @abhitalks i was talking about OP's jsfiddle, when i check is see BODY get 20px from top

Comment: @A.Wolff : Also, the `HTML` was exceeding `body` height when setting the `border`!!

Comment: @A.Wolff: Yup. I saw that too. That is not margin, actually the body shifts down by that much margin. In dev tools margin is shown in light orange. If you see body, it will show that gap in black.

Comment: @abhitalks you are correct i misnamed it, should have use term gap instead, not margin

Comment: @abhitalks +1 for the good answer, but NoobEditor had the solution I needed.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** changed answer for uniform margin this is a bit more work, an extra wrapper div is needed to set the appropriate CSS styles [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mZKC5/15/) -

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class = "dummy">
        <div id="page">
            I am a div sized with calc()!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

new CSS -

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:helvetica;
    background:black;
    color:yellow;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
}
.dummy{
    height:100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    padding 0 10px 0 10px;
}
#page {
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    min-height:90%;
    min-height:calc(100% - 60px);
    width:100px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:20px auto;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.2)
}
```

Comment: that's not a solution vishal. see that fiddle carefully. Op wanted to have uniform margin on top and bottom, but there seems to be more space at the bottom.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood will modify answer

Comment: with this css and markup...u practically changed everything except the text and `calc()`!! :)